# INSERT. Как НЕ вставлять данные

Tags: postgresql

Предположим есть очень простая таблица на две интовые колонки:

```
create table test (first int, second int);
```

Я вставляю в нее данные разом, используя следующий запрос:

```
insert into test (first, second) values (1,2), (2,3), (4,5);
```

При этом часть запроса с данными `(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)` после `values` я строю из переменной типа `List`. Таким образом возможна ситуация, когда `List` придет пустой и получится ошибка, так как запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
insert into test (first, second) values ;
```

Как можно переписать данный запрос, или какое дефолтное значение подставить, таким образом, чтоб запрос мог правильно интерпретироваться и выполниться без ошибок, но при этом фактически ничего бы не вставилось. Что-то вроде:

```
insert into test (first, second) select 1,2, where false;
```

только подкрутить этот запрос для моей ситуации с множественными вставками.

Comment: сделайти валидацию List до генерация самого запроса.

Comment: Что мешает проверить List на пустоту и вообще не выполнять никакого insert?

Comment: а если уж так хочется генерировать запрос то можно так: insert into test (first, second) values (default, default)

Comment: Не могу. Я использую функциональный `orm`, который композирует различные `IO`. Один `IO` может быть скомпозирован только с другим `IO` и ничем другим, а значит даже если лист пустой, то мне все равно нужно составить какой-нибудь `IO` для данной ситуации. А сам `orm`, к сожалению, не предоставляет пустого `IO` (ну либо я его не нашел). Максимум что можно, это для пустого листа составить запрос `select 1`, но мне хотелось бы одним запросом.

Comment: еще в postgresql можно вроде так insert into test (first, second) default values; 'https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html'

Comment: но при этом вы можете повлиять на то как именно строится запрос и не можете - не делать запрос вовсе? Как так?

Comment: @Yaroslav Попробовал с `default`. По факту это не пустой запрос, он делает вставку пустых значений.

Comment: @Oleg, добавьте к таблице default value. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-default.html

Comment: @Мелкий представьте что у вас функция возвращает `Int`. Вы не можете написать в ее конце `return if (cond) 1;`. Ваша программа не скомпилируется, так как не все ветви кода возвращают `Int`. Вам нужно будет приписать еще часть `else someDefaultInt`, верно? Вот у меня точно такая-же ситуация, только из функции я возвращаю объект сформировавшегося, но еще не выполненного запроса к БД. Что-то вроде  `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Yaroslav Это не совсем то. Я бы хотел написать такой `insert`, который по факту никак не изменяет БД. Вот еще для примера. `insert into test (first, second) select 1,2, where false;` выполнится без ошибок. но фактически никак не изменит БД. Вот мне бы как-то подкрутить это для моей ситуации с множественными вставками, если такое возможно.

Comment: Что у вас за язык такой, что простейшие `if` не поддерживает?  Если у вас хаскел. то используйте `Data.List.NonEmpty`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Проблема не в языке а в `FRM`, который не дает "пустого" `IO`, либо аппликатива, чтоб его построить. Либо во мне - человеке, который не смог его найти :) Язык кстати `Scala` и `if` там есть. Вопрос как раз о том, что поставить в секцию `else`, чтоб запрос не падал с ошибкой.

Comment: @Oleg  В таком случае, закрывайте этот вопрос и открывайте вопрос по _Scala._  Именно с вопросом «Как поставить `else`».

Comment: @Ainar-G Я хотел понять, как такое провернуть именно в `sql`, безотносительно языка, из которого я делаю запросы. Имея такое знание, я смогу перевести это на Scala уже самостоятельно, без открывания новых вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into test (first, second) 
select *
  from (values(NULL, NULL),
    (1,2), (2,3)  -- Ваш список
  ) a(first, second)
 where first is not null or second is not null
```

Comment: Как раз то. что нужно было.